# Counting number of different clients when they appear multiple times in a database

Tags: excel

I have a client database that lists clients and the dates of the sessions they come in for counseling. They might come in, for example, 4 times per month. The spreadsheet lists the client name several times, showing each time they came in. Using an Excel pivot table, is it possible to find out how many different clients came in for the month without removing duplicates? There seems to be a problem in the totals when I remove duplicate client numbers.

Comment: Could you add some examples? Maybe add the table definitions and some sample data? It's pretty hard to determine what you are trying to achieve without some (anonymised) data.

Answer (score 0):

From Excel 2013 onwards you can use DISTINCT COUNT by adding your data to the data model when creating the pivottable.

Process is outlined [here](http://www.howtoexcelatexcel.com/formulas/excel-tip-how-to-count-unique-items-in-excel-pivot-table/):

> Select your data set (CTRL+A)
>
> Hit CTRL+T
>
> Confirm your data table has headers
>
> Create your Pivot Table in the usual way by selecting the data table
>   (or the shortcut keys ALT+N+V)
>
> Insert Tab – Tables Group – Pivot Table
>
> To ensure you can use the Distinct Count function this is where where
>   MUST tick Add This Data To The Data Model in the Create Pivot Table
>   Dialog Box
>
> Simply drop the field you want to make a unique count of into the
>   Values area in this case it is Client Names
>
> Then navigate to the Value Field Settings of the value you added
>
> At the bottom of the list you will now see Distinct Count (this does
>   not appear if you do not click Add To Data Model)

So with example data:

[image: Sample data]

Distinct count from pivot added to data model:

[image: Distinct count]

Resulting count:

[image: Result: Distinct count]

Comment: This is fantastic!  Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Please consider upvoting or marking as answer. Box top left. Green tick.